# how to move <li> element from one <ul> to another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<ul id="List">
<li class="li">1</li>
<li class="li">2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".li");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
 items[i].onclick = function(){
 const list = document.getElementById("List2");
 list.insertBefore(items[i], list.childNodes[0]);
 }
}
```

im trying to move the clicked `li` element to another `ul` with the `insertBefore` method but it doesnt do anything when i click on one of the li elements, how can i do this? or am i doing anything wrong? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure JS solution**   
***EDIT: The second solution is the more correct one***

You can use `append` like :

```js
const listone = document.querySelector("#List");
const listwo = document.querySelector("#List2");
var li = listone.querySelectorAll("li");
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].onclick = function() {    
    listwo.append(this);
  }
}
function MoveLi(el){

}
```

```css
#List li{
  color:red;
}
#List2 li{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="List">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>


<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

---

After some tips in the comments, `addEventListener` solution:

```js
const listone = document.querySelector("#List");
const listwo = document.querySelector("#List2");
const li = listone.querySelectorAll("li");
function MoveLi(){
  listwo.append(this);
  this.removeEventListener("click", MoveLi);
}
li.forEach( (el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", MoveLi);
});
```

```css
#List li{
  color:red;
}
#List2 li{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="List">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>


<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

Comment: **Never** use `onclick` unless you create brand new elements from in-memory. Use the better additive method `Element.addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: There's no need to (unless supporting ancient browsers) to use a `for` loop when using `querySelectorAll`. You have `NodeList.forEach()` at your disposition. Also, it's bad practice to define functions inside for loops.

Comment: Why _it's bad practice to define functions inside for loops_ ?

Comment: To not talk about computational performance I'll give you only the main reason: it's a function. Define it in one place, use where needed.

Comment: Amongst other things you LI elements are still clickable even when inside the designated List2 - that's why I suggested not to assign click handlers to the LIs in the first place. - but well that depends on the OPs specific task needs.

Comment: You have right i change code with `addEventListener`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan with new solution the `<li>` is clickable again in the second `<ul>` why?

Comment: Simone, see my solution. The handler is assigned to the Original UL only - not to the LI. Even if you move the LI elements they will still have the handler attached and act strangely.

Comment: I've seen, but technically why?

Comment: because the handler is assigned to each LI - instead it should be assigned to the parent UL `#List` element.

Comment: Oh yes now i understand and in your opinion is it wrong to remove `EventListener` using `removeEventListener` as in my example above?

Comment: Ok thanks for your time, never stop learning right? ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's a way too. - PS.... You still don't need the for loop...

Comment: Also,don't use `var` - you risk polluting the GlobalThis (`window`) scope. Stick to the self scoping  `const` and `let`...

Comment: I think everything is ok now isn't it?

Comment: Why `let li` instead of `const li`? Use `let` only for what's going to change.

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, `const` is used as variable that doesn't change correct? In this case it changes

Comment: Your `li` are not going to change - unless they are. Not in this case.

Comment: if var contains 2 `<li>` of first `<ul>`, when i click on it will contains just one no?

Comment: Simply place `console.log(li.length)` inside the `MoveLi` function and you'll see for yourself. It will always yield `2`. Therefore no, it's not going to change. Just out of curiosity, from what programming language background you're coming? PS: a nice article I've found you might be interested in: https://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/08/25/why-not-making-functions-within-a-loop-in-javascript/

Comment: Mostly I use PHP, of course I also have to use js / jquery to finish any projects.
I actually miss some concepts since the schools I did despite being computer science did little in depth js / jquery and php

Comment: Ah @RokoC.Buljan thanks again for your time

Comment: You'll want to use `let` only in cases when i.e: you do something like `let book = "";` and than in other places of your code you need to `book += page1;` ... `book += page2;` or like: `let price = 15;` and than later `price += 20;` - otherwise stick always to `const`. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

As you've tagged jQuery in the question, this can be achieved by using `appendTo()`. As you've only got 2 `ul` elements in the DOM the logic is simply to append the clicked `li` to the `ul` which is not its parent. Try this:

```js
let $uls = $('#List, #List2');

$('li').on('click', e => {
  let $li = $(e.target);
  $li.appendTo($uls.not($li.closest('ul')));
});
```

```css
/* Just to make the demo clearer: */
ul { border: 1px solid #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="List">
  <li class="li">1</li>
  <li class="li">2</li>
  <li class="li">3</li>
  <li class="li">4</li>
  <li class="li">5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, how can target the specific `ul` instead of the `ul` that is not the parent?

Comment: Never just use `e.target` without going for `.closest()` - A possible `<span>` element inside the `<li>` is not the *`target`* you want.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan right, but that's not relevant to the HTML here.

Comment: @coder you can call `appendTo()` directly on the element you want to target, eg. `appendTo('#List2')`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that cannot be true. Wait for OP to place any child element - or another developer stumbling on your answer with a different case. I always advocate to train muscle memory by typing always `Event.currentTarget` - and only when necessary (Event delegators) use `Event.target` together with `.closest()`. - Use `target` only when you really, really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

- Assign the click handler to the original UL element  - otherwise your LI elements will swap positions even after appended to the target UL (List2)
- Use [Event.target.closest("li")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to retrieve the LI element
- Finally, use [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

```js
const EL_list = document.querySelector("#List");
const EL_list2 = document.querySelector("#List2");

EL_list.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  const EL_LI = ev.target.closest("li");
  EL_list2.append(EL_LI);
});
```

```css
#List2{background:gold;}
```

```html
<ul id="List">
  <li class="li">1</li>
  <li class="li">2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="List2"></ul>
```

**Tip:** Never use `onclick` unless you create brand new Elements from in-memory. Use the better additive method [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead